# pygame mouse events not register smoothly

Tags: python, pygame

I try to build a game using pygame and have issues with mouse events. Basically even if I click the exactly same place, two different kinds of events will register at different time. For example if I click on monster.rect, if may register as I click another rect, which have no intersection with monster.rect, then if I move my mouse a little bit and move back and re-click on the exact same position and then it registered correctly. Here is my code:

```
    def check_events(screen, monster, buttons, button_status):
        """Check mouse and keyboard evetns"""
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()


            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                if monster.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()): #If click monster cards
                    button_status.monster_initial_active()     #active monster initial button
                    print('click')


                elif buttons:
                    for button in buttons:
                        if button.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                            if button.text == 'Play':
                                monster_play()
                            elif button.text == 'Level up':
                                monster_level_up()
                            elif button.text == 'Back':
                                monster_back(button_status)
                                print(button.rect)


            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                print('0')
```

Please help me if you can, thanks!
Code in the main loop:

```
     while True:

        gf.check_events(screen, monster, buttons, button_status)

        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, character_1, character_2, monster, tactic, buttons, button_status)



        clock.tick(25)
```

Comment: What does the output way (your print debugs) and what positions does everything have at the time of the click? (mouse x,y and each buttons x,y and also the monster)

Comment: Please edit your post and provide a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it's really difficult or even impossible to find the bug.